# Why there is always some noise in the rendered text of freetype?

Tags: c, opengl, freetype

I'm writing a opengl program that use freetype2 as text rendering engine.

Using its LCD subpixel rendering, I found that there are always some noise pixels in the rendered result, why is that happening? Besides, although it's manual says that the LCD mode will generate buffer with width a multiple of 3, I often found the width to be 3n+1 or 3n+2, and inconsistent with the `face->glyph->bitmap->width`.

[image]

Comment: It tries to compensate for parity with the +1 and +2.

Comment: How is +2 compensating parity? It doesn't change the parity.

Comment: See my comment on Lie Ryan's answer (and accept it if you like; I don't need rep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, after hours of trying and testing, I realized that the rasterized glyph data has some non-relevant bytes called `padding`. Illustratively, imaging below is a glyph data in a buffer: (`o`/`x` are meaningful data, while `.` are non-relevant)

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 o x o x o x . .
1 x o x o x o . .
2 o x o x o x . .
3 x o x o x o . .
4 o x o x o x . .
```

There are three numbers describing the size of this buffer, the first two are obvious:

```
rows = 5    //since there are 5 rows
width = 6   //since each row has 6 bytes of data
```

However, there is actually a third one:

```
pitch = 8   //the actual width of rows, including "padding"
```

If you ignore this property of buffer like me, and got the wrong idea that the `width` is the actual width, you'll be rendering a distorted or translated glyph shape.

My understanding of this 'padding' is like Dhaivat Pandya has said, it's a compensation. However, it's not a compensation for parity, (obviously +2 is not changing parity,) by default it's a compensation to make the actual width a multiple of 4. But yes, you can change the 4 into 2 or even 1. I guess by forming a data matrix with its width a multiple of 4, it can be loaded faster, for example, to be loaded in `longint` instead of `byte`.

But still, the insightfulness of `R..` really impressed me. I think you guys just can't image I could make such a basic mistake.

Comment: Having a "length" that's distinct from the "stride" (or "pitch" here) is a fairly common design pattern in APIs that handle a series of fixed items in a raw buffer. As you note, it's usually for faster aligned access. Bitmap data is often stored with alignment padding this way (since the "width" of an image can be any integer at all), and if you do graphics, vertex data usually can be as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used FreeType library, so I can't talk by personal experience, but maybe that "noise" is because your text width or your calculation of the top-left text coordinate is off by one?

Comment: This is correct. The circled pixel in the image is not supposed to be the rightmost pixel of the line it's shown on. Instead it's the leftmost pixel of the following line. OP's pointer to the beginning of the image is off by one pixel.